# add two class on scrolling page

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a class on page scroll. I have done it successfully. Now I want to add one more class on more scroll. But I am not getting the proper way. Here is my HTML code.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('header').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/Photo-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here `shrink` class is added on scroll. and it is removing on back scrolling. Now I am trying to add another class on more page scroll. For example `shrink-new`. But i am not getting proper way. I think i am missing the condition. Anyone please help to do this. I am not expert in java. So please help me by your simplest answer. I have found a lot of answer about this. but I am not understanding those.

Comment: What do you mean by 'on more scroll'?

Comment: it means when user goes down it add ``shrink``. I want to add one more class when user scroll down more. I mean if page is 400px height. then when user scroll for 50px it add ``shrink`` class. now I want to add ``shrink-new`` class when user scroll more then 100px.

Comment: So add another `if` statement checking `scrollTop > 100`...

Comment: I have tried. But it is not working.

Comment: I added an answer for you showing exactly how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you simply need to add another `if` statement which checks if `scrollTop()` is over 100px:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
  $('header').addClass('shrink-new');
} else {
  $('header').removeClass('shrink-new');
}
```

Also note that you can make this logic much more succinct by using `toggleClass()` and providing a boolean value which determines whether the class should be added or removed:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  $('header').toggleClass('shrink', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
  $('header').toggleClass('shrink-new', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```

```css
.shrink { zoom: 0.5; } 
.shrink-new { background-color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/Photo-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

To get new class on scroll you simple use .scroll function in jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  $('header').toggleClass('shrink', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
  $('header').toggleClass('shrink-new', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```